# Kendo DropDownList not firing validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, jquery-validate, kendo-dropdown

I have Kendo DropDownList bind with model. Now I have applied required validation in model but it is not firing. I don't know what is the issue.
Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required.")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

ViewPage:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.Gender)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .OptionLabel("---Select---")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .AutoBind(true)
    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" }
    })
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender, null, new { style = "color:red;float:left" })
```

For other model properties, it is firing validation.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/16571760/2630817

Comment: @Justcodenot working.

Comment: Can you show me your updated code?

Comment: @Justcode same as above.

Comment: Please look into [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/validation)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery.validate 1.9+ then  by default it ignores hidden inputs and the dropdownlist uses one to hold the value. In order to enable the validation in this case you should override the validator default settings e.g.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' });
```

for detail you can refer the link 
[click here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/mvc-unobtrusive-validation-doesn't-work)